# finding unique value in object array list and creating separate array based on unique value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array object list like this

```
feedbasestatsobjectlist->
                  statslist->
                      [0]->timetype = "hour"
                           timestamp = "408069"
                           event = "release"
                      [1]->timetype="min"
                           timestamp = "24484150"
                           event = "release"
                      [2]->timetype = "hour"
                           timestamp = "408069"
                           event = "success"
                      [3]->timetype="min"
                           timestamp = "24484150"
                           event = "success"
                      [4]->timetype = "hour"
                           timestamp = "408069"
                           event = "something"
                      [5]->timetype="min"
                           timestamp = "24484151"
                           event = "something"
```

Now on iterating on this array object list I want to create 3 seprate array based on the values.
First array will have values of timetype = hour with timestamp = 4048069
so array will be

```
array_1->
      timetype = 'hour'
      timestamp = '408069'
      event = 'release','success','something'
array_2->
       timetype = 'min'
      timestamp = '24484150'
      event = 'release','success'
 array_3->
       timetype = 'min'
       timestamp = '24484151'
       event = 'something'
```

so basically combining the same time stamp values into separate array.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `foreach($statslist as $stat) { $newarr[$stat['timestamp']][] = $stat; }`

Comment: @MarcB This assumes he's sorting only by timestamp. The question looks like he's asking to sort by unique combinations of timestamps and timetypes.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks that helps